# facing issue while assign the value to the variable in node js

Tags: node.js

the HTTP request the output data is coming in the console. I need to assign to a variable

```
const options = {
  hostname: 'abcdef',
  port: 443,
  path: '/xyz',
  method: 'GET',
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  requestCert: true,
  agent: false
};

https.request(options, (res) => {
  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);// this will print to the console
  });
}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
}).end();
```

I am new to node.js please help me with this issue.

Comment: Using directly the HTTP/HTTPS package is not recommended for simple use cases and new users, you'd be more confortable using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

Comment: Have you tried to google how to assign a value to a variable in node js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't set `encoding` for `response` so its data will be display as `Buffer`. You need to `res.setEncoding('utf-8');` to get string value from response's data

Comment: ```res.on('data', (d)``` in this function you have got the data. It is ```d```